# Convert name of dataframe to string within a function

Tags: r, function

I have many dataframes which I want to run through a function which creates a directory with the name of that dataframe as the folder name.

I have tried:

```
Create_dir = function(data){
   filename = deparse(substitute(data))
   dir.create(filename, showWarnings = FALSE)
   }
```

And

```
Create_dir = function(data){
   list = lst(data, "x")
   filename = names(list)[1]
   dir.create(filename, showWarnings = FALSE)
   }
```

And a few other methods which all work well outside functions, but inside the function they either name the folder "data" or don't work because filename equates to a list of strings of all the data in the dataframe.

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is simple if all the data frames are in a list, and you use names of the list as the names of the files. This is hard otherwise--hard to be general. If you have "many data frames" I assume you don't want to individually write out `Create_dir(mtcars); Create_dir(iris); Create_dir(diamonds); ...`, so think about how you want to iterate over your data as that will influence the answer.

Comment: Your first function works for me. `TestFolder <- data.frame()` and `Create_dir(TestFolder)` makes a folder named "TestFolder" in my working directory. Maybe you mean for your question to be, "these functions worked when called from the global environment, but not from within other functions"?

Comment: Hi Gregor, I was going to use a for loop over a list: for(i in list){ Create_dir(i)}

Comment: Ian, thanks, same actually, it must be obstructed by some of the other code in the function then. I will have another look

Comment: What advantage does this approach offer over creating the directories from `names(list)` for example `sapply(names(list),dir.create)`? If the list is unnamed, then you had to have had the names of the `data.frames` to create the list.

Comment: Hi Ian, the function does a whole bunch of stuff that it then puts into the folder which it creates, but that wasn't relevant to the question. But you were right it works now, I just moved the code to the top of the function and it was fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The first function actually works, thanks, apologies.